# Nested if, check is pointer is valid then check value

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement

This question has been bugging me for a while

Is it usual to have a piece of code that works like this:

```
bool failed = false;
if (ptr)
{
    if (ptr->value == foo)
    {
        print("error");
        failed = true;
    }
}
if (!failed)
{
    print("all systems go");
}
```

Or can it be done with out the bool?
I guess the first two ifs could be on one line but im not sure what order they are checked in different environments and I think it might make it harder to read.

Comment: What is the context? For one, you could replace the first two ifs with `if (ptr && ptr->value == foo)`. But the definitive code will depend on the rest of the code which is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All compilers should follow the same [precedence order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), so the check can be replace by this:

```
if (ptr && ptr->value == foo)
{
    print("error");
    failed = true;
}
```

If the first part (the lone `ptr`) is false, then the rest of the expression will not be evaluated. This is called short-circuiting.

Comment: Thanks! and thanks for the link that i should have just googled

Answer (score 2):

You can always rely on boolean operators [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
const bool failed = (ptr != NULL) && (ptr->value == foo);
```

This will not evaluate the second part if the first  (`ptr != NULL`) evaluates to false.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your condition like this :

```
if (ptr && ptr->value == foo)
{
    print("error");
}
else
{
    print("all systems go");
}
```

In C++, conditions are evaluated lazily. As soon as final result is known, the evaluation stops. So for OR, the first true stops the evaluation, for a AND, the first false ends the evaluation

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with conditions. Short-circuiting is a property of the boolean operators.

Comment: Thanks for being more precise than I am ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can certainly do this:

```
if (ptr && (ptr->value == foo) )
{
    print("error");
}
 else
{
    print("all systems go");
}
```

You are guaranteed that logical AND and logical OR are evaluated from left to right and that evaluation will stop when the result is known. So this is safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need you `failed` boolean later on, that code does exactly the same.

```
if (ptr && ptr->value == foo) {
    print("error");
} else {
    print("all systems go");
}
```

The order of the checks in the if-statement is well-defined and the `&&`-operator skips the second comparison `ptr->value=foo` if the first expression is not true.

Answer (score 0):

you can just write `if(ptr && ptr->value == foo')`

C ensures, that if first condition will fail, second condition will not be checked at all. It is because FALSE & ANYTHING == FALSE.